# Delete removed videos from playlist youtube-dl

Tags: systemd, youtube-dl

I have a script that syncs my yt playlist to my computer. Problem is, when I remove a video from my playlist it stays on my computer. Is there a way to either have youtube-dl delete the video or to have youtube-dl genereate a list of files so I can remove the ones that are not on it?